# Not able to install mariadb on mac mini

Tags: mysql, mariadb, macos-big-sur

I have installed mariadb on a mac mini m1 using:

```
brew install mariadb
```

The I get the following error:

```
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall mariadb
==> Caveats
A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built
server starting up correctly.
```

I've checked /etc/my.cnf but there is no such file

I don't get any errors when running:

```
brew services start mariadb
```

but when running:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

or

```
mysql
```

I get:

```
zsh: killed     sudo mysql -u root
```

or

```
zsh: killed     mysql
```

respectively.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you have an old version of `/etc/my.cnf` try to remove the file and reinstall mariadb with brew.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much an answer, but...

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/Build_Environment_Setup_for_Mac/

Have you considered trying to build from source?  I don't have a lot of experience building from source myself, only a few successful Linux builds under my belt, but I've read that this is what is required on the new M1 Macs.  I couldn't find that link again.  I haven't bought an M1 Mac mini yet, but I want one - and whether or not I could install mariadb is what is stopping me as of now.